# How to display international scripts in QLabels?

Tags: string, fonts, internationalization, pyqt4

I would like to display Indic, Arabic and Hebrew scripts in a QLabel, specifying the font type. When I try to pass a UTF-8 encoded string into a QLabel, the script is not rendered properly.

What is the correct way to display international (non-alphabetic) scripts in a QLabel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the text of a `QLabel` to a unicode string (`unicode` in python2, `str` in python3) should work fine.

In python2 you can use `QString.fromUtf8` to convert a utf8-encoded `str` to an unicode `QString`, or `.decode('utf-8')` to a python `unicode`.

In PyQt4 on python3 `QString` is gone as now `str` is already unicode, so just use that.

For instance:

```
    s = "اردو"
    d = s.decode('utf-8')
    label = QtGui.QLabel(d)
    font = QtGui.QFont("Sheherazade", 40)
    label.setFont(font)
```

Comment: I added a working example, because I still had some trouble from your explanation alone.