# Unicode text displayed improperly in QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pyqt

When trying to display a name in a QLabel like `Thermíte` it shows up as `ThermÃte`.

I've tried decoding and encoding into various formats to get it to work with no luck. The name is pulled from a bsObj into a list of strings.

Later it is added into `Qlabel.setText(.....+master_stats[1]+.....)`.

There is various html formatting around the string for color changes and appending other text.

Comment: What does the repr of the string look like?

Comment: from trying to print `print(repr(master_stats[1])` I get `UnicodeEncoderError: 'charmap' codec can't encode charater '\xc3' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I managed to use urllib's quote against it so now I have `b'Therm%C3%83%C2%ADte` maybe it'll be easier to convert this back into `Thermíte` for the QLabel ?

Comment: Oh bloody hell, it's double-encoded. Is the web server returning the proper charset for the contents?

Comment: Ignacio is alluding to the fact that you have to know the encoding of the string.  Once you figure that out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575533/how-to-display-international-scripts-in-qlabels

Comment: according to the Response headers it's utf-8. [https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/garrosh/thermíte?fields=stats&locale=en_US&apikey=hkeaxkcd76x69g7kwnzk7vcxf9wreqvs] is the request i'm making with urllib]. The request won't work atm I don't think since it's bound to my account. but this is in the http resonse headers `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
`

Comment: Yep, that is saying the page uses the UTF-8 encoding, however C3 83 is utf-8 for `LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE`, which is what you are getting.

Comment: OK, now I need to find a way to get it to show up as it's supposed to in the label

Comment: Well, the web page author can put anything the want for the Content-Type header, and in your case they lied.  The next most likely encoding would be Latin-1, but the *i with accent* would be ED in latin-1.

Comment: Ahem...or you screwed up.  At this point, I would go with the latter--until proven otherwise.

Comment: What is the output of: `soup.original_encoding`? If that isn't utf-8, then try doing this: `soup = BeautifulSoup(b'html', from_encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: `'í'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1').encode('utf8')` -> `b'\xc3\x83\xc2\xad'`.  So looks like it was misdecoded as `latin1` or `windows-1252` and re-encoded as UTF-8 somewhere along the line.

Comment: ok so I ran it while printing `.original_encoding`. It appears that it's coming in as `windows-1252`. so I changed the call to `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html_stats.read(), from_encoding="utf-8")` and now everything is working fine. I'm getting a parser warning from bs4 now. It's the whole `No parser was explicitly specified` one. Can that be resolved? or will it just be something I'll have to ignore? Maybe change the call to `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html_stats.read(), from_encoding="utf-8", "html5lib")` ?